# How to fast pagination csv dataset data in any language

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I have a dataset in csv (comma separated value) format. want to page 40 000 rows. Is there a tool which satisfies this request? Or How can I do in python3?

[image: first 3 rows]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What should be your desired output? Have you tried something?

Comment: My problem is elasticsearch pagination. We are fetching 40000 documents from elasticsearch using scroll API. We have given 10 slices and scroll size is 4000. But slice API is taking more time to fetch all data from elasticsearch. I say you about one minute

Answer (score 0):

there is a python library called https://vaex.io/ which is for parsing millions of data.
It's for when it takes a long time or you get blocked by pandas.
A dataset of 50,000 rows and 40 columns takes me 7s with pandas. I don't think it's much